# Extract a specific value from this data type

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this script to get data from a database

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE catid = 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row['extra_fields'];
}
```

The output is:

```
[{"id":"1","value":"johndoe"},{"id":"2","value":"marydoe"}]
```

I want to extract/print only the value corresponding to `"id":"1"` (that in this case is 'johndoe'). I'm not able to extract it from the above data type.

Comment: Why not just build your query to extract that particular id?

Comment: Where is your select statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is the code that fits my needs:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $array = json_decode($row['extra_fields']); 
  $value = $array[0]->value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To read [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) use

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $array = json_decode($row['extra_fields'];
  // Do something with $array['id'] 
}
```

Did you realise you can directly go for that data in MySQL?

```
SELECT value FROM items WHERE id = 2;
```

**edit:**

Basically your query is

**SELECT** comma-separated column names or star for all, use only what you really need to save bandwidth, e.g. `SELECT id, value`

**FROM** table-name, e.g. `FROM mytable`

**WHERE** columnname = desired value, e.g. `WHERE id = 2`

You want to query only the required columns in the required rows. Imagine one day you would have to parse 1 million users every time you want to get an id... :)

Comment: The first part of your answer is helping me to find the final solution, but I'm interested in the second one! I've edited the first post with the real SELECT i'm using. Is there a better Select that allow to directly select the 'value' (corresponding to 'id'=1)?

Answer (score 0):

The output is [JSON](http://www.json.org/). Use PHP's `json_decode` function.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $array = json_decode($row['extra_fields']);
  foreach($array AS $item) {
    echo $item['id'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do it in the mysql query part. For example, set the ID = 1 in the query.